# How can submit my form through mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email-templates, php-7.2, mail

I have automated mail sending function in Magento 1.9 code.

I have used mail template for sending mail (using default magento functionality)

but now i want to add one form in that mail which contains some MCQ type question and it get answerd by user who receive mail.

And it get saved on Magento side for future scope/reference as well as once user submits that form one email should go to Magento admin also.

I expect result as ,

1) By cron or manually mail sent to user/customer and in that mail body contains one form which have MCQ type 3 or 4 question.

2) After submitting that form by Customer or user there answer should save on Magento Side

3) After submitting Form A mail should go to Magento Admin with there answers

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: No you cant check this link - https://www.123formbuilder.com/docs/can-i-embed-my-online-form-into-an-email/

Comment: I get alternate solution 
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689011/9092636** from here